# Centering text to center in parent but not in TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout for toolbar view, where I have one ImageView on left side, TextView on center and on right zero, one or two ImageView. And I need to center text of TextView to be at center of window but not in center of space between left and right icons.

Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:background="@color/darkGreyTextColor">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/rightBarrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="rightFirstIcon,rightSecondIcon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightFirstIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rightSecondIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightSecondIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rightSecondIcon"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_locate"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightSecondIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@{viewModel.navigationStatus.topNavigationTitle}"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightBarrier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test small text"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the result is 
[image: Two icons on right]

But I can change visibility of right icons and the view will be look like this:
[image: One icons on right]
or
[image: No icons on right]

What I need to do to always center text in my TextView to be center on window?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be, Creating a layout with the edit text using the full width. Then in another layout add the Imageviews with their orientations. Finally place the second layout on top of the the first layout.

Answer (score 0):

Talking UI, what is implemented now is the best, but if you insist on making it center parent in all cases, it's simple, just make layout dependencies refer to the parent:

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: It's not resolved my problem. When text is large it overlap icons.

Answer (score 0):

I have same task.

I need place 3 items (left, center, right) and ellipsize center TextView if it needed.

Left and right items can be hidden or have dynamicly width

**Example:**

[image: example].

I choose FrameLayout with gravity attributes for items:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Clickable"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_semibold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="Filter team" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_action"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Clickable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_regular"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="Apply" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And i call **resizeTitle** after update content of items:

```
private fun getVisibleWidth(view: View): Int {
    return if (view.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        view.measuredWidth
    } else {
        0
    }
}

private fun resizeTitle() {
    binding.root.post {
        val leftWidth = getVisibleWidth(binding.ivBack)
        val rightWidth = getVisibleWidth(binding.tvAction)
        val totalWidth = getVisibleWidth(binding.root)

        binding.tvTitle.updateLayoutParams {
            width = max(totalWidth - max(leftWidth, rightWidth) * 2, 0)
        }
    }
}
```